# Number of connected components of a given curve inside a particular set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Assume that $(X,d)$ is a metric space and let $\Omega\subset X$ be a open set with $\operatorname{int}(\overline{\Omega})=\Omega$.

Let $\alpha :[0,1]\to X$ be a Lipschitz curve and consider the two sets $\overline{\Omega}\cap\alpha([0,1])=U_1$ and $(X\setminus\Omega)\cap\alpha([0,1])=U_2$.

I am trying to prove (maybe it is not true) that the number of connected components of $U_1$ and $U_2$ is finite. Any idea is aprreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual metric. Set $\alpha(t) = (t, 0)$.

Now let $\Omega$ be the area under the graph of $x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$. That's a continuous function, so $\Omega$ is an open set and the function is its boundary.

It should be easy to see both $\overline{\Omega}\cap\alpha([0,1])$ and $(X\setminus\Omega)\cap\alpha([0,1])$ contain countably infinite number of connected components.